# Почему фор не перебирает список? В чем моя ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = list(input())
x = int(input())
lenght = len(lst)
for i in range(lenght):
    if lst[i] == x:
        print(lst[i])
    else:
        print("Отсутствует")
```

Я вроде бы понимаю, что не проходит первый элемент, но цикл ведь вложен в for, он должен дальше перебирать список....

ввод: 567856880 и число 8
вывод: отсутствует((
требуемый вывод: (индексы, на которых стоит число 8 в списке) 367

Comment: `list(input())` возвращает список из букв. `int(input())` возвращает число. Никогда буква не может оказаться равной числу. Вот и не находит.

Comment: но мне по условию дан список чисел, как тогда можно переделать задание, чтоб правильно искало?

Comment: А вы его читаете как список букв. Делайте так `lst = list(map(int, input().split()))`.

Comment: В случае малейшего сомнения печатайте переменные и проверяйте что ваши ожидания совпадают в реальностью.

Comment: все равно сразу в элс скачет и не проходит весь список... (так я поняла что дело оказалось в длине списка (равен единице), но почему он перебирает если сделать for i in lst?)

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что вы вводите, что получаете на выходе и что вам нужно чтобы было на выходе.

Comment: `lst = list(map(int, input()))`

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = input()
x = input()
for i, y in enumerate(lst):
    if y == x:
        print(i, end='')
print()
```

> ```
> $ python search.py
> 567856880
> 8
> 367
> ```

Или так:

```
lst = input()
x = input()
answer = ''.join(str(i) for i, y in enumerate(lst) if y == x)
if answer:
    print(answer)
else:
    print('Отсутствует')
```

Comment: уже решила 
спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = list(map(int, input()))
x = int(input())
lenght = len(lst)
if x not in lst:
    print("Отсутствует")
else:
    for i in range(0, lenght):
        if lst[i] == x:
            print(i, end = " ")
```

Спасибо Станиславу за подсказки!

Comment: Тут не принято благодарить. Но спасибо! (Всё равно вопрос закроют :).